# Is it possible to change a textbox's text which is in english to tamil in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, textbox, translation

#### Question

How do I translate text a user types from English to another language? What APIs exist for this?

#### Background

When a user types in text into a `TextBox` on my ASP.NET page, I want it to be automatically translated into Tamil.

Comment: Do you mean to want to automatically translate English to Tamil?

Comment: i want it to be done programmatically... User wont see it when he types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google provides a service to translate text:

[AJAX Language API for Transliteration](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/#Transliteration)

Comment: Nice. Now I know how they do this in orkut !! + 1 from me

Answer (score 1):

@Pandiya: I believe you are talking about [transliteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration)  and not [translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation). Your intended output should be something like [this](http://www.azhagi.com/autot.html) ??. A search gave me [this](http://unicode.org/resources/keyboards.html) which pointed me to [this software](http://www.kuralsoft.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I know of that could do this is [Microsoft's translator](http://blogs.msdn.com/translation/), however it does not appear that Tamil is a supported language as of yet.